# How to generate a Banyan network for n-inputs

Tags: python, networking, routes, switching

I'm trying to understand how one might automatically generate a Banyan Network for n-inputs in code. I haven't been able to get much help from my research so far.

This is what a 8-input banyan network looks like.. 
[image]

How do I model each node in code? is there an algorithm I can use to generate the nodes and paths for an n-input Banyan network?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps nothing related to Banyan network itself, but since Python tagged you could check if [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) could provide any help to your problem. At least it makes easy to implement the network itself.

Comment: thanks for this! Even though it didn't help with the original problem, I found it useful when doing kcore analysis a week later!